# Run local script with arguments with docker

Tags: bash, docker, powershell

I am trying to run a local script with docker bash in windows PowerShell but not working.

My script part is another program, but the finally goal is to process a media file and zip it with the shell script.

The cmd: `docker exec -it containername /bin/bash < myscript.sh -f fileone.mp4 -h output`

I have an error in ps:
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.

The parameters *(and also the files)* are changing, if rerun the shell script, and after the script, processing is done it will create a zip file *(what I need)* with the output name, but random strings will be placed to the zipped filename too.

Anyone tried to use docker in that way in windows?

Comment: Try `docker exec -it containername "/bin/bash < myscript.sh -f fileone.mp4 -h output"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Almost, but only works with winpty, And if it's not installed, just docker, then it's not working. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: What is the main container command; why do you need a debugging tool like `docker exec` to do this?  If your main goal is to read and write host files, would it be easier to also run the process directly on the host, without involving an isolation layer like Docker?

Comment: Firstly the application is based on WSL (it's a desktop application), it's worked, but in different windows systems, the WSL has not worked well and caused so many bugs in the main application. So the wsl logic replaced with docker, all the necessary tools and settings installed setted with docker-compose and dockerfile,  now the only thing to figure out, what I wrote before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out a solution for my own question. I just leave it here, if someone needs it.

The docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services: 
  somename:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: 'name_if_you_need'
```

The dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:latest
# Install and/or config anything what you need
ADD . /newfolder
WORKDIR /newfolder 
ENTRYPOINT [ "/newfolder/myscript.sh" ]
```

To call *(with arguments and/or flags if your script need it)*: `docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/newfolder image_name -flag1 sample.mp4 -flag2 sample` *(no tty error, not need winpty)*

*Please note, if your script working with file or files, and you pass it via arguments like me, you need to copy them in your current folder before docker run*

With this solution, if your script generates a file or files when/after executing, you will see them automatically in your current folder.